# Regex expression to find keywords in a string along with following characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of known keywords, like `'cat', 'dog', 'rat'`.

I have a string that can be something like this:

```
'rat;dog,cat - browncatdog(black)ratratcatdog-whitecat:grey'
```

I need to find all the keywords plus any characters that are immediately following them (not including delimiters like semicolon and comma as well as the next keyword).

So the result from the string above should be this list:

```
'rat', 'dog', 'cat - brown', 'cat', 'dog(black)', 'rat', 'rat', 'cat', 'dog-white', 'cat:grey'
```

I've tried a few ways but end up getting items that contain multiple keywords, or missing some keywords.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1417356/edit) to include the expected results, what you have tried so far (something more specific than "a few ways") and how it fails to meet expectations

Comment: is it always and only rat, cat and dog for the 'main' keywords?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> [(f[0], f[1][0]) for f in re.findall(r'(rat|dog|cat)(.\w+)', 'rat;dog,cat - browncatdog(black)ratratcatdog-whitecat:grey') if re.match(r'(cat|dog|rat|[,;])', f[1]) is None]
[('cat', ':')]
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible using pure regex.
A trick would be to add a deliminator before all keywords and to split afterwards.

```
>>> s = "rat;dog,cat - browncatdog(black)ratratcatdog-whitecat:grey"
>>> re.split(r"[;,]+", re.sub(r"(cat|dog|rat)",r",\1",s))
['', 'rat', 'dog', 'cat - brown', 'cat', 'dog(black)', 'rat', 'rat', 'cat', 'dog-white', 'cat:grey']
```